# What is the name/part number of this 1x1 LEGO brick, used to make "cat eyes"?

Tags: part-identification

Could anyone please tell me the name/part number of the LEGO component used for the cat's eyes?

[image]

Comment: I always love it when LEGO constructions use ordinary bricks in creative ways :-)

Answer (score 22):

**Name:** Lever Small Base 4592.

Bricklink link *[HERE](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4592&name=Lever%20Small%20Base&category=%5BLever%5D#T=C)*.

[image]

Comment: Peeron calls it "Hinge Control Stick Base", but the same code.

Answer (score 12):

Looks like https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4592c02#T=C but with the lever removed.

[image: Lever Small Base with Black Lever]